# Как сделать, что бы окно черепашки (turtle) не закрывалось после выполнения программы?

Tags: python, turtle

У меня черепашка делает круг, и окно сразу закрывается:-(

```
import turtle
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.shapesize(2)
turtle.color('green')
for step in range(6):
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(60)
turtle.hide_turtle()
```

Answer (score 4):

Нужно добавить в конце:

```
turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop() или turtle.done()
```

И еще исправить ошибку:

```
turtle.hideturtle() вместо turtle.hide_turtle()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import turtle


turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.shapesize(2)
turtle.color('green')

for i in range(6):
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.right(60)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()
```

1. `Turtle` нужно импортировать в начале кода.
2. По правилам `PEP-8` после `for` нужно писать англ. буквы, начиная с `i`.
3. Чтобы окно не закрывалось, можно использовать 3 варианта:

```
turtle.mainloop()           # Стандартное зацикливание из Tkinter
turtle.done()               # Рисунок закончен
turtle.exitonclick()        # Выход при нажатии мышкой в окне Turtle
```

В принципе, все.